# AngularJS - ReferenceError: "someScopeVar" is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a feedback-form with AngularJS, where the user data is stored in `$scope.feedback`. Now I want to include a progress bar and need to determine the percentage.

```
    // $scope-variable to hold the data.
    $scope.feedback = {
        title : undefined,
        name : undefined,
        email : undefined,
        tel : undefined
    };

    // Get the total amount of attributes of $scope.feedback
    var totalAmountOfAttributesOfFeedback = 0;
    for (var k in $scope.feedback) {
        if ($scope.feedback.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            ++totalAmountOfAttributesOfFeedback;
        }
    }

    // Get the amount of defined attributes of $scope.feedback
    // to determine the percentage of Progress
    $scope.determinePercentageOfAttributesDefined = function () {
        var amountOfDefinedAttributesOfFeedback = 0;
        for (var l in $scope.feedback) {
            if (angular.isDefined($scope.feedback[l])) {
                ++amountOfDefinedAttributesOfFeedback;
            }
        }
        $scope.percentageOfAttributesDefined = (amountOfDefinedAttributesOfFeedback / totalAmountOfAttributesOfFeedback)*100;
        console.log(percentageOfAttributesDefined);
    };
```

To calculate the percentage, I am counting the total amount of attributes of `$scope.feedback`.
To count the amount of attributes already filled by the user, there is the function `determinePercentageOfAttributesDefined`, which is called whenever an input field is touched.

The problem is, that the variable `$scope.percentageOfAttributesDefined` is not defined and I get the following error in the browser console:

```
ReferenceError: percentageOfAttributesDefined is not defined
```

I also tried creating the variable somewhere else in my controller, but get the same error. Does somebody know the reason for that?
Other Scope-Variables such as `$scope.feedback` can be accessed without a problem.

Thanks for taking the time :)

Comment: can you please check with `console.log($scope.percentageOfAttributesDefined);`

Comment: @GirdhariAgrawal That was it appearantly. The only problem was that the log didnt work because I forgot the $scope.

... Thank you

Comment: can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log($scope.percentageOfAttributesDefined);`

This should solve your problem.